# How to evaluate mean reciprocal rank(mrr) is a good model

Tags: machine-learning, model, metrics

such as AUC have a metrics

a good model will be over 0.7
great one will be over 0.85.

I want to know mean reciprocal rank(mrr) metrics evaluation.

how to define this is a good model.

very thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The metric MRR take values from 0 (worst) to 1 (best), as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_reciprocal_rank). However, the definition of a good (or acceptable) MRR depends on your use case. For example, if you build a model to be used in a recommender system, and from thousands of possible items, recommend a set of five items to users, then an MRR of 0.2 could be defined as acceptable. This means that on average, the correct item the user bought was part of the top 5 items, predicted by your model.

All in all, it mostly depends on how many possible classes are possible to predict, as well as your use case.